# Words whose pronunciations change in sentence

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation

How/where can I find the list of words whose pronunciations depend on the next word in the sentence, like `the`?

Comment: The only ones I could find that are labeled as such in a learner's dictionary are *to* and its derivatives, such as *into*, *onto*, etc. But note that most words undergo some kinda change (for instance, a lot of vowels get reduced to schwas in faster speech, which isn't restricted to English, and a lot of words change depending on the preceding / following word). I found this by looking up *the* in the OALD and figuring out how that's labeled, and then googling with the OALD's FQDN after `site:` together with `"before vowels"`, so this might not be as thorough and the list as exhaustive.

Comment: For me, I never change the pronunciation of *the* based on the word that follows it. I'm aware of that convention, but I don't follow it. I always say *thuh*. The only time I say *thee* is when I want to put emphasis on the article itself. It doesn't matter in either case what word follows it.

Comment: @Jason Bassford You almost definutely add a glottal stop before a vowel.